# Get sum of value in list using lambda in java

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

I have a list containing Node object

```
class Node {
  int id;
  int value;
  Integer parentId;

  Node(int id, int value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
    this.parentId = null;
  }

  Node(int id, int value, int parentId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
    this.parentId = parentId;
  }
}

List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
nodes.add(new Node(1, 10));
nodes.add(new Node(2, 3, 1));
nodes.add(new Node(3, 2, 2));
nodes.add(new Node(4, 1));
nodes.add(new Node(5, 2, 4));
```

I wanna get the sum of values with given parentId by traversing to the end using Java Lambda functions.

[image]

For example for the above values,

if parentId = 1, result is 15 because Node 1 children are Node 2 and Node 3

if parentId = 2, result is 5 because Node 2 children are only Node 3

Which lambda function should I use to traverse over list and get sum of value?

Comment: Can you detail more how you get your sum ??

Comment: Yes, there is only one `Node` with `parentId` of 2 and one with 1 and one with syntax error.

Comment: It seems like you need to implement the Depth-first search algorithm (or Breadth-first search, alternatively). This can be implemented in a really cool way with map/reduce.

Comment: Why it is 15 when parentId = 1 and it is 5 when parentId = 2??

Comment: @user43968 what type of info do you need? It looks like everything is clear. I have a linked list and I wanna get the sum of values by giving starting node

Comment: @BahramdunAdil, consider a directed weighted graph with a starting node `1`. When traversing through its direct on un-direct children and summing the weights of the edges, the sum is 15

Comment: @BahramdunAdil because when you start summing with node 2, you just discard node 1 value which is 10

Comment: You should fix your description, you are adding all child nodes starting from the parent id. Eg,the tree starting with parent id 1 has 3 nodes. The tree starting with parent id 2 has 2 nodes. Your description makes it sound like, only the nodes with the specific parentid.

Comment: @matt thanks. I have updated the description. I hope it is more clear now

Comment: Do you have an array list containing a linked list? Can multiple nodes have the same parent? Nice diagram.

Comment: @matt There could be multiple nodes with the same parent. All nodes are in ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I want to restructure your Node a little bit.

```
class Node{
    final int id;
    int value;
    Node parent;
    public Node(int id, int value){
        super(id, value, null);
    }
    public Node(int id, int value, Node parent){
        this.id = id;
        this.value=value;
        this.parent=parent;
    }
}
```

Now I will use a filter that asks, "Does this Node go through the correct parent."

```
public int getSome(int parentId){
    return nodes.stream().filter(n->{
        if(n.id==parentId) return true;
        Node c = n;
        while(c.parent!=null){
            c = c.parent;
            if(c.id==parentId) return true;
        }
        return false;
        }).mapToInt(n->n.value).sum();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lambda expression in a recursive method. Something like this (not tested):

```
public int getTotal(List<Node> nodes, int parentId){
  int total= 0;
  nodes.forEach( n -> {
    if(n.parentId == parentId)
      total += getTotal(nodes, n.Id);
    if(n.Id == parentId)
      total += n.value;
  });
  return total;
}
```

Looks like java didn't like my non-final variable 'total'. A fix for this: ideone.com/BFVmmC

Comment: Helpful, but can be improved to be non-recursive with map/reduce. :)

Comment: *local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final*

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov Why whould that be an improvement? :-)

Comment: `return nodes.stream().mapToInt(n -> n.id == id ? n.value : Objects.equals(n.parentId, id) ? getTotal(nodes, n.id) : 0).sum();` would also works, I guess (although not very readable).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the easiest way is just to(not tested, sorry, I can do it during the day):

then, if we use a built-in interface, it's like

```
Function<List<Node>, Function<Integer, Integer>> getSum = 
    (list) -> 
    (parentId) -> list.stream()
    .filter(x-> x.parentId.equals(parentId)) //with required parentIds
    .mapToInt(y-> y.getValue()) //
    .sum()
```

Or you may declare a functional interface like

```
interface getNodesSum{
    getSum(List<Node> list, Integer parentId)    
}
```

and put the same code.
But all in all, unless you don't have several thousands of values, the only purpose of using streams and lambdas is that they look cool.
If you are expecting to sum more than 5000 values, you could use parallelStream.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dmitry-belkin but it is not the expected answer. Your solution does not traverse to the end of graph, it looks for only one depth in the graph. I think I need some graph algorithms using lambda expressions.

Comment: Ah, got it now - when reading the question yesterday, I didn't see the picture. I'd like to think over an elegant solution.